# Ao tentar extrair um PDF usando Python Textract, retorna um erro

Tags: python, ocr

Estou usando a biblioteca Python, que é o Textract, para extrair texto de um arquivo PDF, mas está obtendo um erro ao executar o script. Abaixo está o script e o erro retornado no console.

```
import textract

text = textract.process("C:\Users\Willian Ambisis\Downloads\licenca-ambiental2.pdf")
print(text)
```

Erro:

> File "c:\Users\Willian Ambisis\Desktop\Textract\textractPython.py",
> line 3
> text = textract.process("C:\Users\Willian Ambisis\Downloads\licenca-ambiental2.pdf")
> ^ SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode
> bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Answer (score -2, accepted):

O problema se dá porque você está tratando as barras invertidas do caminho do arquivo como caracteres normais ao invés de caracteres especiais. Da [documentação](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals):

> O caractere de barra invertida (`\`) é usado para escapar os caracteres que, de outra forma, têm um significado especial, como nova linha, a própria barra invertida ou o caractere de aspas.

Tente adicionar o prefixo `r` à sua string, que lida com as barras invertidas por você:

```py
import textract

#                       v
text = textract.process(r"C:\Users\Willian Ambisis\Downloads\licenca-ambiental2.pdf")
print(text)
```

Answer (score -1):

Esse erro é causado porque você tá usando uma string normal como endereço doa rquivo. Pra solucionar tem 3 possibilidades:

1: Adicionar `r` antes da string pra converter de normal em `raw string`:

```
text = textract.process(r"C:\Users\Willian Ambisis\Downloads\licenca-ambiental2.pdf")
```

2: Inverter as barras:

```
text = textract.process("C:/Users/Willian Ambisis/Downloads/licenca-ambiental2.pdf")
```

3: Usar barras duplas para escapar o caractere:

```
text = textract.process("C:\\Users\\Willian Ambisis\\Downloads\\licenca-ambiental2.pdf")
```

Answer (score -2):

Além de o caminho do documento estar com contrabarra ao invés de barra que pode ser corrigido utilizando um r antes da string de caminho o textract processa imagens, então é necessário utilizar uma conversão do pdf para imagem a menos que se carregue direto do s3.